# Timers in a .NET application

Tags: c#, .net, timer

I would like to know what kind of timers can be used in a C# application and what are their implications in term of cuncurrency in a multi-threaded environment.
Could you explain me or link me to an esaustive tutorial?
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two forms of timers - ones that are message based, and typically UI centric, and ones that are thread-based.

The UI versions are the [Timer class from Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) or the [DispatcherTimer in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx).  These tend to report timings (normally) on the UI thread, and basically use the standard message pump to handle timing.

The [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) and [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) classes use a separate thread for handling timers.  These work very well, but the "Tick" events happen on a separate thread.  This means you need to handle thread synchronization or UI threading synchronization if you use these.