# Timer usage in Thread Pool

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, timer, threadpool

I am developing a windows application for my company that runs on the server. It is a multi threaded application, and i am using Thread Pool for that.

My Application Email module consists of 3 major methods. 1st method gets new campaigns from database, second method decides to whom the campaign is going to be sent via email and third method sends it.

When I start the application, 1st method goes into Thread Pool, if there is a new campaign, 2nd method is invoked with the campaign info. But while these all are happening, first method has to check database in every three seconds if there is a new campaign or not.

I am not sure if I have to use System.Windows.Forms.Timer class for that or System.Threading.Timer??

And I am not sure how to implement it? Am I going to use Invoke Function to invoke thread outside the main UI? Could you please post an example code and suggest best practices??
Thanks a lot

Here is my code :

```
private void btnStart_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        smartThreadPool = new SmartThreadPool();
        workItemGroup = smartThreadPool.CreateWorkItemsGroup(1);
        workItemGroup.QueueWorkItem(CheckNewCampaigns);
        //smartThreadPool.QueueWorkItem(new WorkItemCallback(this.CheckNewCampaigns));            
    }

    private object CheckNewCampaigns(object state) // 1st method
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        IEnumerable<Campaigns> CampaignsList = DatabaseManager.GetCampaignsList(DatabaseManager.GetNewCampaigns());

        foreach (Campaigns Campaign in CampaignsList)
        {
            builder.AppendFormat("New Campaign Arrived($) --> {0}\r\n", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
            builder.AppendFormat("CampaignID              --> {0}\r\n", Campaign.CampaignID);
            builder.AppendFormat("CustomerID              --> {0}\r\n", Campaign.CustomerID);
            builder.AppendFormat("ClientID                --> {0}\r\n", Campaign.ClientID);
            builder.AppendFormat("Title                   --> {0}\r\n", Campaign.Title);
            builder.AppendFormat("Subject                 --> {0}\r\n", Campaign.Subject);
            builder.AppendFormat("Status              --> {0}\r\n", Campaign.Status);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());

        workItemGroup.QueueWorkItem(new WorkItemCallback(this.PrepareCampaignEmail), 2);
        return true;
    }

    private object PrepareCampaignEmail(object CampaignID)  // Second Method
    {
        int campaignID = (int)CampaignID;
        IEnumerable<Campaigns> CampaignDetailsList = DatabaseManager.GetCampaignsList(DatabaseManager.GetCampaignDetails(campaignID)); // bir tane campaign gelmekte
        IEnumerable<Subscribers> SubscribersList = DatabaseManager.GetCampaignSubscribersList(DatabaseManager.GetCampaignSubscribers(campaignID));
        ArrayList test = new ArrayList();

        DataTable dtCustomValuesForCampaign = DatabaseManager.GetCustomValuesForCampaign(campaignID);

        foreach (Subscribers subscriber in SubscribersList)
        {
            workItemGroup.QueueWorkItem(new WorkItemCallback(this.SendEmail), subscriber.Email);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: And there's also [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx)! (And [System.Windows.Threading.DispatchTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) in WPF) Check out this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313677/timers-in-a-net-application) and its answer to clear out any confusions about all those timers.

Comment: Have you tried system.Threading.timer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, since it's a Windows Forms application and you'll potentially want to update the UI in the timer event handler, I'd suggest using `Windows.Forms.Timer`.

Using `Windows.Forms.Timer` is pretty easy.  In the design view of your form, select the `Timer` from the Toolbox and drop it on your form.  Then, click on it to set the properties.  You want to set `Interval` to `3000` (that's 3000 milliseconds), and `Enabled` to `False`.

On the Events tab, double-click the Tick event and the IDE will create a handler for you.  You want the event handler to look something like this:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var stateObj = // create your state object here
    CheckNewCampaigns(stateObj);
}
```

You'll need to start the timer (set `Enabled` to `True`).  You can do that in your `Create` event handler, or you can enable it when the user hits the Start button.  You can also stop it at any time by setting `Enabled` to `False`.

Answer (score 1):

`System.Thread.Timer` and `Windows.Forms.Timer` act differently.

The `System.Thread.Timer` will run on a **system** thread. It has an internal thread pool, so it won't be run on one of the threads you explicitly created. Every interval, one of the threads in the Timer's pool will run the callback you initialized the object with.

The `Windows.Forms.Timer` will raise the `Tick` event on the **current** thread and will do so every interval, until you disable it.

I can't tell you which is more appropriate for your situation; it depends on whether you want to run the timer on the UI thread, as well as other factors.

Comment: The timer will affect only one method. I think it will be better to create the timer on the current thread with Windows.Forms.Timer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void EnableTimer()
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
                this.Invoke(new Action(EnableTimer));
            else
                this.timer1.Enabled = true;
        }
```